# BigQueryでJSON文字列を保存して配列になっている値を集計したい場合のやり方

Tags: google-bigquery

Qiitaの以下のエントリをみて、これができるとログの解析が捗りそうと思い色々試してみています。
http://qiita.com/hakobera/items/5e280ad33d72f82de39c

JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALARを使えば値を取り出せるのでこれで集計用のテーブルを作れば要件満たせそうと思っていたのですが、保存されているJSONデータに配列がありました。

たとえば以下のような感じのログデータがBigQueryのテーブルのlogdataというカラムに入っているとして、

```
{
  "date": "2015-08-31",
  "time": "00:00:00",
  "type": "RESPONSE",
  "userno": 12345,
  "friends":[{"userno":1, "nickname":"hogehoge"}, {"userno":1, "nickname":"fugafuga"}]
}
```

最悪は、

```
select 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(logdata, '$.friends[0].userno') friend0,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(logdata, '$.friends[1].userno') friend1
from serverlog_20150831
```

のようにして配列の数だけ並べたらいいのかもしれませんが
FLATTENのように配列の数分だけ別のレコードになるように取り出すうまい方法がないだろうかと思い調べています。

どなたか良いアイディアがありましたらご教示ください。

Answer (score 2):

がんばってやってみました！

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT (logdata, '$.userno') AS userno,
  "{"+ REGEXP_REPLACE ( SPLIT ( JSON_EXTRACT (json, '$.friends'), "},{"), "^\\[\\{|\\}\\]$","") + "}" AS friend
FROM
  serverlog_20150831
```

これの結果が以下です。

```
Row userno  friend   
1   12345   {"userno":1,"nickname":"hogehoge"}   
2   12345   {"userno":1,"nickname":"fugafuga"}
```

そして、更にここからjsonをばらしていって

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT (logdata, '$.userno') AS userno,
  JSON_EXTRACT("{"+ REGEXP_REPLACE ( SPLIT ( JSON_EXTRACT (logdata, '$.friends'), "},{"), "^\\[\\{|\\}\\]$","") + "}",'$.userno') AS friend.userno,
  SUBSTR(JSON_EXTRACT("{"+ REGEXP_REPLACE ( SPLIT ( JSON_EXTRACT (logdata, '$.friends'), "},{"), "^\\[\\{|\\}\\]$","") + "}",'$.nickname'), 2,LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT("{"+ REGEXP_REPLACE ( SPLIT ( JSON_EXTRACT (logdata, '$.friends'), "},{"), "^\\[\\{|\\}\\]$","") + "}",'$.nickname')) -2) AS friend.nickname
FROM
  serverlog_20150831
```

とすると、以下になります。

```
Row userno  friend_userno   friend_nickname  
1   12345   1               hogehoge     
2   12345   1               fugafuga
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

SPLITでバラした文字列を更にJSON_EXTRACTするという発想がなかったです。これは有用ですね。試してみます！

Answer (score 0):

StandardSQL版を作成しました。
Debug用にすごいばらしてあるけど、やってることは基本的に同じ。

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  userno,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(friend, "$.userno") AS friend_userno,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(friend, "$.nickname") AS friend_nickname
FROM (
  SELECT
    userno,
    CONCAT("{",REGEXP_REPLACE(friend, "^\\[\\{|\\}\\]$",""), "}") AS friend
  FROM (
    SELECT
      userno,
      friend
    FROM (
      SELECT
        userno,
        SPLIT( friends, "},{") AS friends
      FROM (
        SELECT
          JSON_EXTRACT('{"userno":12345,"friends":[{"userno":1, "nickname":"hogehoge"}, {"userno":1, "nickname":"fugafuga"}] }}', "$.userno") AS userno,
          JSON_EXTRACT('{"userno":12345,"friends":[{"userno":1, "nickname":"hogehoge"}, {"userno":1, "nickname":"fugafuga"}] }}', "$.friends") AS friends ))
    CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(friends) AS friend))
```

Answer (score 0):

UDF で JSON.parse する手はどうでしょう。

```
#standardSQL
# STRUCT の型は JSON に合わせる
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  parse_logdata(logdata STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT>>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(logdata);
""";
# LOGDATA_TABLE にログが入っている前提
WITH
  LOGDATA_TABLE AS (
  SELECT
    '{  "date": "2015-08-31",  "time": "00:00:00",  "type": "RESPONSE",  "userno": 12345,  "friends":[{"userno":1, "nickname":"hogehoge"}, {"userno":1, "nickname":"fugafuga"}]}' AS logdata
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '{  "date": "2015-08-31",  "time": "00:00:00",  "type": "RESPONSE",  "userno": 12346,  "friends":[{"userno":1, "nickname":"foobar"}, {"userno":1, "nickname":"piyopiyo"}]}')
SELECT
  logdata.userno AS userno,
  friends.userno AS friend_no,
  nickname
FROM (
  SELECT
    parse_logdata(logdata).*
  FROM
    LOGDATA_TABLE) AS logdata
INNER JOIN
  UNNEST(logdata.friends) AS friends
```

追記: UDF の入ったクエリの同時実行数には注意する必要があるかも。
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?hl=en
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions?hl=en#limits
また、 VIEW では使えないし BI ツールでも使えないのが普通ですね。